# Stop IR shutting down PC

Tags: windows-media-center, shutdown, ir

I have a PC that I'm using as a Media PC.  It doubles as a mail server too.  The problem I have is that my universal remote control sends the signal to my media center PC to turn on/off as everything else turns on/off.  This of course kills my mail server, plus my PC never wakes from sleep happy and blue screens anyway.
Is there a way to tell Windows 7 to ignore the IR commands to sleep or wake?  Or is there some way to get the eHarmony software to leave my Media PC alone but still give me the Media Center commands when everything turns on?
I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your power management utility and see if there is an item for power state commands sent from a remote.

If there is not an item for commands from a remote, set the commands that are there to "Do nothing" or "Ask me what to do" when the power button is pressed, when the sleep button is pressed, and the like.